# If the set of roots has cluster point then function is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, holomorphic-functions

If $f$ is a holomorphic function defined on an open and connected set, and the set of zeros of $f$ has a cluster point/accumulation point/limit point then it is identically $0$.

I can't think of a way to proceed. Any hints are appreciated

Comment: $f$ can be represented by Taylor series in cluster point, all coefficients of the series have to be zero, starting with the constant one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you stated is a particular case of the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).